# SSIS package saved in Database server can't be executed from the app server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I currently have 2 servers (Database and Application). I've deployed 3 packages to my Database server, when I run them from the same server, everything works fine but when I open my Application server -> SQL Management Studio and try to run the stored procedures it's telling me that I can't open the file to be imported.

When i run the stored procedure from my app server, does it run under a specific/default user?

Comment: It looks like there is an invalid file path used within the stored procedure or the SQL server account doesn't have access to the file path specified

Comment: i'm using my Windows Authentication to log into the SSMS. When i execute the stored procedure it executes under some default user? because my user should have access to the file but a default sql account might not.

Comment: @Check that `NT SERVICE\<SQL Instance Name>` account has access to the folder. WHERE`<SQL Instance Name>` is the instance name.

Comment: Have your DBA troubleshoot the permissions involved.